# MySQL relationship issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I've two tables structure is below

```
person (id, fname, lname, ph, mob, dob, email)
address (id, address1, address2, address3, town, county, postcode)
person_address (id, person_id, address_id)
```

I've have a issue here, if one person have more than one address how would i work out which is active or current address, should i add a direct link of address table such as `person (id, fname, lname, ph, mob, dob, email, address_id)`

or should i add a link to person_address link to person table `person (id, fname, lname, ph, mob, dob, email, person_address_id)`

any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, a person can have only one current address.  If so, you should add a column into the `person` table, called something like `CurrentAddress`.

If you *require* a current address, you can even declare `CurrentAddress` to be `NOT NULL`.

If a person could have more than one current address, then use a flag in `person_address`.

Now, if you want the current address to be the most recently inserted address, you can use a trigger to reset the value on each insert.  Or, if your database is not too big (thousands of rows, not millions of rows), you can calculate it on the fly by choosing the `person_address` record with the most recent creation time.

EDIT:

@Joanvo's point is a good point.  You can fix it by adding a foreign key constraint in `person` referring to  to `person_address`.  You will have to create a unique constraint on `current_address(person_id, address_id)` and use that for the foreign key.

Comment: I like the idea of adding a flag to person_address. This only drawback on this is if you use an ORM, it's not trivial to add properties to a relation table. In the end I've had to create a new model for the rich relation.

Comment: This approach will give you the problem of having to check the consistency every now and then, you'll have to guarantee that the foreign key in current address exists in the table person_address for that person.

Comment: @Joanvo . . You can add a foreign key constraint so that is not a problem.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a bit in the person_address table to indicate if it is the current address or not. Make sure there are not more than one current addresses via sql or code checks:

```
person_address (id, person_id, address_id, current)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a reference of the *person_address* table into the *person* table that would create a circular dependancy between *person_address* and the *person* table, since the *person_address* table already encapsulates a reference to the *person* table. Thing that you should never do when dealing with database design.
Now, If you want a clean design, I would recommand to a reference from the *adress* table to the person table like you did in your first example. So your design solution will be like follows:

```
person (id, fname, lname, ph, mob, dob, email, address_id)
```

**EDIT:**

Or a solution will be a *current_flag* in your *person_adress* table, so when you want to have the current address for a person, you will search for the *person_adress* entry that has the *current_flag* set to 1 for that person.

```
person_address (id, person_id, address_id, current_flag)
```